# If a function $f:X\to R$ is discontinuous is the derivative also discontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis

If a function $f:X\to R$ is discontinuous is the derivative also discontinuous? I'm not sure if this statement is true or false.

Comment: If the derivative existed, the function would be continuous...

Comment: @Peter: that's true if $X$ is an interval in the line, but Sarah has kept her $X$ secret from us.

Comment: @GEdgar True. In the answer, I addressed pointwise behaviour, but still with $\Bbb R^n$ on my mind. If that is not the case, I'll delete.

Answer (score 6):

For any function $f$, $f$ being differentiable at a point implies $f$ is continuous at that point. Thus, if $f$ is discontinuous at a point, it can't admit a derivative there.